# Add Active Class to Manufacturer & Information Module OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to add an `active` class so it can be styled to the manufacturer & information modules. I got both working to show in the left column like the regular categories.
But I'm having problems with adding the active class to it.

I've tried to clone the code from the `category.tpl` to add the active class like this in
`catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/manufacturer.tpl`

```
<div class="box"> 
    <div class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $heading_title; ?></span></div> 
    <div class="box-content">
        <ul class="box-category"> 
            <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?> 
            <li>
                <?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a> 
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?> 
            </li> 
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's not working, can anyone help me with this?

OpenCart 1.5.6

Comment: Is the variable `$manufacturer_id` set in the controller? In Your controller You should have something like this: `$this->data['manufacturer_id'] = $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];`.

Comment: hm i got;      $this->data['manufacturer_id'] = $parts[0];  } else {   $this->data['manufacturer_id'] = 0;

Comment: But that `$parts[0]` is used in catagories, where You have `path` parameter in URL. Within Your module I believe You have a `$_GET['manufacturer_id']` parameter, therefore You need to set it like `$this->data['manufacturer_id'] = $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];`.

Comment: Ah nice one step closer, thank you so much, this solved it but only when browsing manufacturers, when having the category menu at the same page, and browsing one of the, I get a Undefined index: manufacturer_id for the changed line on the controller file

Comment: ah well of course, need to set   } else { $this->data['manufacturer_id'] = 0 , Thank you very much!

Comment: I summarized these comments into an answer below so that You could accept it. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Your module I believe You have a `$_GET['manufacturer_id']` parameter, therefore You need to set it like

```
if($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']) {
    $this->data['manufacturer_id'] = $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
} else {
    $this->data['manufacturer_id'] = 0;
}
```

This will use the `manufacturer_id` from query string part of the URL if present or set it to `0` if not.

Comment: Update: This solves the manufacturer module, but information module only works when SEO is turned off, so index.php?route=information/information&information_id=1 gives an active class from the information.tpl but with SEO turned on, it gives nothing. Should this be asked as a new question?

Comment: That is strange, because the the URL `http://my.opencart.com/about-us-information/` should be in the end rewritten into `http://my.opencart.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=1` so if You do `echo $this->request->get['information_id'];` in Your controller, it should print out `1`. If not, something is wrong with Your url_rewrite...

Comment: Yes is prints out 1, so the rewrite seems fine, could it be something with the information.tpl then? I've got  <?php if(isset($_GET['information_id']) && $information['information_id'] == $_GET['information_id']){ ?>